# Add Class to div when a specific word appears a specific number of times on page

Tags: javascript, html

So, my aim is to add a Class name to a div but only when the word "premium" appears 10 times on the page.

My current code below adds a Class whenever the word "premium" appears. However, I need the Class name to only be added after 10 instances of the word.

**.listing-package** is the div where the word "premium" occurs and **.submit-post** is the div that I need to add a Class name to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Cheers :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    document.querySelectorAll('.listing-package').forEach(el=>
    {
        if (/premium/.test(el.textContent) )
        { document.querySelector(".submit-post").classList.add("disabled") } 
    })
})
```

Comment: i don't understand your purpose clearly, do you want just to add class "disabled" once you count 10 "premium" class element on your page ?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me - much appreciated! No, I want to add the class "disabled" once the text PREMIUM has appeared 10 times in the div "listing-package".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll` gives a list of elements that contain a certain tag like a class or an id. Maybe you could use its length to know if it has 10 (or more) elements.

Comment: The premium word will appear as a text not as an element

Comment: Not sure about that, you normally will receive a NodeList with each HTML-element that you could count for his purpose.
To show what I mean, type on this page in the console the following code: `document.querySelectorAll(".spacer")`

Comment: I could easily add "premium" as a class, if that helps, but how would I adapt my existing my code? Apologies, as I said to @Nayan, I'm not 100% confident with Javascript. Thanks in advance and thanks for your time.

Comment: Try to change your if-clause to this: `if (/premium/.test(el.textContent) && document.querySelectorAll('.listing-package').length >= 10)`. This will work if there are 10 or more elements with a div containing "premium". If you want this to be exactly 10 and not more, change the `>= 10` to `== 10`.

Comment: Absolutely spot on! Brilliant. Thanks @NicolasRégnier. That works perfectly. Code below for clarification:
`$(document).ready(function() {   
    document.querySelectorAll('.listing-package').forEach(el=>
    {
        if (/premium/.test(el.textContent) && document.querySelectorAll('.listing-package').length == 10)
        { document.querySelector(".submit-post").classList.add("disabled") } 
    })
})`
Have yourself a drink tonight!

Comment: You're welcome ;) tell me if you need anything else ^^

Answer (score 0):

Change `premium` word check in `if` condition.

```
if ((el.textContent.match(/premium/g) || []).length >= 10)
```

Comment: Thanks @Nayan. Unfortunately I am receiving errors with the above code  - the FULL STOP before "length" and the final BRACKET after "10". Javascript is the thorn in my coding side so any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Check updated answer